# passing object value to directive instead of any other data variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to customize this working http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/JNqqU/  ,in current working fiddle directly object is assigned . where i am trying to change it to $scope.obj.items . passing object to directive is not working .

do i need to write some $watch fo r the variable ??? i am getting dynamic value that's why i am trying to pass Object value with this .

Code ::

```
<a href="#" pop-over items="obj.items", title="Mode of transport">
   Show Pop over</a>
```

javascript Directive part ::

```
 scope: {
            items: '=',
            title: '@'
        }
```

Any suggestion ,

**I am trying Below Fiddle** 
http://jsfiddle.net/JNqqU/652/

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, exactly? the object is passed to directive correctly.

Comment: on click of :updateitem" i need to add element in array or say initially on page load it will be undefined or something , api will give back result after some time that value should be pass

Answer (score 2):

You can change your controller to this:

```
bootstrap.controller('maincnt', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = { // declare the scope object here with a blank items 
        items: []
    };
    $scope.updateitem = function () {
        alert('scope update called');
        $scope.obj.items = ['car', 'truck', 'plane', 'bike']; // now update here
    }
});
```

[Checkout fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JNqqU/654/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be making a watcher.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue) {
     buildTemplate(newValue);
  }
});
```

Note: I used watchCollection because it is an array.  If it were an object or simple value $watch would be used instead.

Comment: Sorry your variable names threw me; I should have read closer.  You should use a $watch('items', function () {}, true).  Adding the "true" parameter is optional and should be used sparingly.  The "true" parameter will do a deep watch in case the items change.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap it into object, but don't 'rewrite' whole array in 'update' method, but push values into it:

```
bootstrap.controller('maincnt',function($scope){
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.updateitem=function(){
        alert('scope update called');
        $scope.items.push('car', 'truck', 'plane', 'bike');
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btfu30k2/1/

$watch isn't necessary too.

Comment: initially on page load it will be undefined or something , api will give back result after some time that value should be pass

Comment: my fiddle doesnt reflect updated value in directive  and it is not items it is $scope.obj.items

Comment: So define it as empty array, and in API callback push values into array.

Comment: yes i can do that but i get json in return , so value is not $scope.items it is complex object or like $scope.obj.items

Comment: If you don't have posisbility to define object before API call, then you should use $watch, because there is not way to have reference to initial array.
http://jsfiddle.net/btfu30k2/2/ smth like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need two changes:

Change in HTML `items :: {{obj.items}}`

Change in Controller default obj items should be assigned with empty array ( `$scope.obj={items:[]};` ) as popOver's `$compile` is looking for `scope.items`

See this [**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/k81z6jk5/)

Also your testing code `{{items | json }}` in template can be removed after your observation.